# TextView breaks into multiple Lines

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView called textView4. and I set textView4.setText("First Set of Settings");
the XML of that Textview is

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="Set Locale"   android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
 android:layout_below="@+id/button1"  
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"></TextView>
```

But on the screen it shows

```
  First
  Set 
  of
  Settings
```

No, I want it to First Set of Settings  in one line not breaking multiple lines
So, I set android:lines="1"  then I see only "First"

Comment: I'm thinking it's because your textView2 is aligned to the right of this textview, so it doesn't have the "space" to fit your text on one line. Could you post your full xml?

Comment: Ok, bschulz, you are right, the button1 is hindering the Textview, I moved it out of the way, then now it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

android:singleLine. You can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: In my case, it's hindrance of the button caused it.  Making single wouldn't help.  I move the button out the way and it works now.